# Find numbers in a sentence by regex

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will find all the numbers on a sentence.
For example:
"I have 3 bananas and 37 balloons"
I will get:

3

37

"The time is 20:00 and I have 7 tanks"
I will get:

20

00

7

Comment: Please specify the environment or language you are using. It will allow people to give you more accurate and relevant answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex itself is as simple as `\d+`, but you will also need to set a flag to match it globally, the syntax of which depends on the programming language or software you are using.

**EDIT:** Some examples:

Python:

```
import re
re.findall(r"\d+", my_string)
```

JavaScript:

```
myString.match(/\d+/g)
```

Answer (score 7):

Split your string by `[^0-9]+`.

JAVA: `String[] numbers = "yourString".split("[^0-9]+");`

JavaScript: `var numbers = "yourString".split(/[^0-9]+/);`

PHP: `$numbers = preg_split("/[^0-9]+/", "yourString");`

Answer (score 2):

The regex you are looking for is `[0-9]+` or `\d+`. You should then get multiple matches for the sentence.