# Change string value by regex in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I have this sentence:

"I have 3 bananas at 20:00 o'clock".

I need to replace the number in the string so it will include unicode:

"I have \u200e3\u200e bananas at \u200e20\u200e:\u200e00\u200e o'clock"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2220476/846476 will get you the unicode value. You can do a replace all for \d to find the numbers

Comment: [You seem to like regexps and numbers...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12419998/1225328)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement in your example can be done using [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String string = "I have 3 bananas at 20:00 o'clock";
string = string.replaceAll("\\d+", "\\\\u200e$0\\\\u200e");
System.out.println(string);
```

prints

```
I have \u200e3\u200e bananas at \u200e20\u200e:\u200e00\u200e o'clock
```

Answer (score 0):

Preparing a **hashmap** for digits can solve your problem. Make the numbers as the keys of hashmap whereas the values are the corresponding Unicode values. Then use `replace()` invocations to replace the numbers with their values in the hashmap. I hope this methodology makes sense.